# how to get a real callback from os in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, operating-system

i wrote actionscript and javascript. add callback to invoke a piece of code is pretty normal in everyday life.

but cames to python it seems not quit an easy job. i can hardly see things writing in callback style.i mean real callback,not a fake one,here's a fake callback example:

a list of file for download,you can write:

```
urls = []

def downloadfile(url,callback):
    //download the file 
    callback()

def downloadNext():
    if urls:
       downloadfile(urls.pop(),downloadNext)

downloadNext()
```

this works but would finally meet the maximum  recursion limit.while a really callback won't.

A real callback,as far as i understand,can't not come from program, it's must come from physics,like CPU clock,or some hardware IO state change,this would invoke some interception to CPU ,CPU interrupt current operating flow and check if the runtime registered any code about this int,if has,run it,the OS wrapped it as signal or event or something else ,and finally pass it to application.(if i'm wrong ,please point it out)thus would avoid the function calling stack pile up to overflow,otherwise you'll drop into infinite recursion .

there was something like coroutine in python to handle multi tasks,but must be very carefully.if in any of the routine you are blocked,all tasks would be blocked

there's some third party libs like twisted or gevent,but seems very troublesome to get and install,platform limited,not well supported in python 3,it's not good for writing a simple app and distribute.

multiprocessing, heavy and only works on linux

threading,because of GIL, never be the first choice,and it seems a psuedo one.

why not python give an implementation in standard libraries?and is there other easy way to get the real callback i want?

Comment: Um, that's a "real" callback. JavaScript does it exactly the same way.

Comment: in javascript you can set .onChange = func, how to write it in python?

Comment: Python doesn't run in the browser, so your question doesn't really make too much sense.

Comment: you mean because they are running in different runtimes? what if python also running in similar environment,so my problem would be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is just a complicated way of sequentially downloading all files.

If you really want to do asyncronous downloading, using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, especially the `Pool.map_async` member function. is the best way to go. Note that this uses callbacks.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for multiprocessing:

> "It runs on both Unix and Windows."

But it is true that multiprocessing on ms windows has some extra [restrictions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).